# Interpreting data from /proc/[id]/mountstats or /proc/self/mountstats

Tags: linux, bash, proc

I would like to monitor the IOs of my NFS shares. There are plenty of programs which are interpreting the data within `/proc/[id]/mountstats` ([id] = id of nfs client/server) or `/proc/self/mountstats`. The problem is, these programs calculate some IO per second. This is very nice in the command line, but it is quite useless for my monitoring solution. So I want to interpret the counters of `mountstats` myself. My problem now is, that I need some documentation of `mountstats` for nfs v4.

So far my search haven't brought up any useful.

Thanks for your help

sample output of /proc/self/mountstats on Ubuntu (nfs client):

```
...
device IPADRESS:/mountpoint mounted on /mnt/mountpoint with fstype nfs4 statvers=1.0
    opts:   rw,vers=4,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,acregmin=3,acregmax=60,acdirmin=30,acdirmax=60,hard,nointr,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys
    age:    77663
    caps:   caps=0x1e,wtmult=512,dtsize=4096,bsize=0,namelen=255
    nfsv4:  bm0=0xfdffbfff,bm1=0xf9be3e,acl=0x3
    sec:    flavor=1,pseudoflavor=1
    events: 1462723 25756220 1025148 1164028 1083099 2027020 31347107 1984730 279773 1915700 1346583 21077199 520498 31825 525298 39026 2180470 1083041 0 16822 990144 11011 0 0 0
    bytes:  46686144592 3990939437 0 0 30238687174 3759616491 7739053 1346583
    RPC iostats version: 1.0  p/v: 100003/4 (nfs)
    xprt:   tcp 852 1 2 0 0 11822378 11822377 0 17669710 13357205
    per-op statistics
            NULL: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
            READ: 1950114 1950114 0 330348288 30355844804 105050 6678050 6907640
           WRITE: 911822 911822 0 3932410080 215189360 10653830 1472320 12211620
          COMMIT: 389509 389509 0 65718096 88808052 8060 253550 284360
            OPEN: 1168845 1168845 0 292577612 554554444 430040 628900 1229990
    OPEN_CONFIRM: 43 43 0 7048 2924 0 10 10
     OPEN_NOATTR: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    OPEN_DOWNGRADE: 54 54 0 9952 12744 90 0 120
           CLOSE: 1081161 1081161 0 191495392 255153996 201030 404620 767870
         SETATTR: 43303 43303 0 8753024 10046296 1060 25650 30380
          FSINFO: 2 2 0 268 184 0 0 0
           RENEW: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     SETCLIENTID: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    SETCLIENTID_CONFIRM: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
            LOCK: 1140050 1140050 0 246277244 77523400 76270 326950 469890
           LOCKT: 1 1 0 188 52 0 0 0
           LOCKU: 1037895 1037895 0 187916912 70576860 18130 357530 441480
          ACCESS: 450451 450451 0 72511716 102702828 21440 222460 280950
         GETATTR: 1462724 1462724 0 224029496 310097488 21290 390910 485350
          LOOKUP: 2043380 2043380 0 361899452 532433688 18200 499200 585170
     LOOKUP_ROOT: 1 1 0 116 232 0 0 0
          REMOVE: 32356 32356 0 5953448 7765440 600 15450 18560
          RENAME: 20388 20388 0 5593088 9215376 510 7740 9750
            LINK: 537 537 0 132024 231984 0 220 270
         SYMLINK: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          CREATE: 999 999 0 227376 293140 30 650 830
        PATHCONF: 1 1 0 140 72 0 0 0
          STATFS: 2872 2872 0 419360 333152 580 3980 4880
        READLINK: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         READDIR: 82718 82718 0 14625720 118955760 770 48470 53310
     SERVER_CAPS: 3 3 0 400 264 0 0 0
     DELEGRETURN: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          GETACL: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          SETACL: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    FS_LOCATIONS: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 ...
```

Comment: I have the same question: http://serverfault.com/questions/810729/what-is-snmp-mib-for-getting-nfs-io-counters. Have you found solution for this?

Comment: @JeevanPatnaik Have you looked at https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/NFSMountstatsIndex?

Comment: Hi Thanks..This works. Please make it as an answer!

Comment: Also this with much info: http://www.fsl.cs.stonybrook.edu/~mchen/mountstat-format.txt

Answer (score 7):

Complete source: [http://www.fsl.cs.stonybrook.edu/~mchen/mountstat-format.txt](http://www.fsl.cs.stonybrook.edu/%7Emchen/mountstat-format.txt)

```
       Format of NFS mountstat
```

Linux kernel version: 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64

Important files for statistics:

```
- linux/fs/nfs/super.c: nfs_show_stats
- linux/include/linux/nfs_iostat.h: nfs_stat_eventcounters
- linux/net/sunrpc/stats.c: rpc_print_iostats
- linux/net/sunrpc/xprtsock.c: xs_tcp_print_stats
```

## Server Capabilities (caps)

1. caps:    server capabilities
2. wtmult:  server disk block size
3. dtsize:  readdir size
4. bsize:   server block size
5. namlen:

## nfsv4 (nfs_show_stats)

1. bm0: attribute_bitmask[0], which attributes are supported
2. bm1: attribute_bitmask[1], which attributes are supported
3. acl: acl_bitmask, which acl attributes are supported

## sec, security flavor in effect for this mount (nfs_show_stats)

1. flavor:          auth->au_ops->au_flavor
2. pseudoflavor:    auth->au_flavor

## Events (linux/nfs_iostat.h: nfs_stat_eventcounters)

1. inoderevalidate
2. dentryrevalidate
3. datainvalidate
4. attrinvalidate
5. vfsopen
6. vfslookup
7. vfsaccess
8. vfsupdatepage
9. vfsreadpage
10. vfsreadpages
11. vfswritepage
12. vfswritepages
13. vfsgetdents
14. vfssetattr
15. vfsflush
16. vfsfsync
17. vfslock
18. vfsrelease
19. congestionwait
20. setattrtrunc
21. extendwrite
22. sillyrename
23. shortread
24. shortwrite
25. delay
26. pnfs_read
27. pnfs_write

## Bytes (linux/nfs_iostat.h: nfs_stat_bytecounters)

1. normalreadbytes
2. normalwritebytes
3. directreadbytes
4. directwritebytes
5. serverreadbytes
6. serverwritebytes (serverwrittenbytes)
7. readpages
8. writepages

## xprt (tcp)

- linux/net/sunrpc/xprtsock.c: xs_tcp_print_stats
- linux/include/linux/sunrpc/xprt.h: struct rpc_xprt

1. srcport:         Ephemeral port
2. bind_count:      How many rpcbind operations
3. connect_count:   How many TCP connects
4. connect_time:    How long connects have taken
5. idle_time:       How long transport has been idle
6. rpcsends:        How many socket sends
7. rpcrecvs:        How many socket receives
8. badxids:         How many unmatchable XIDs have been received
9. req_u:           Average requests on the wire (slot table utilization)
10. bklog_u:        backlog queue utilization (average length of baklog queue)
11. max_slots:      max rpc_slots used
12. sending_u:      send q utilization
13. pending_u:      pend q utilization

## Each RPC operation type shows (rpc_print_iostats)

The stats recording: rpc_exit_task ---> xprt_release ---> rpc_count_iostats

All NFS protocols are explained here: http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Topics/115.htm

0. The name of the op type
1. ops              How many ops of this type have been requested
2. trans:           How many transmissions of this op type have been sent
3. timeouts:        How many timeouts of this op type have occurred
4. bytes_sent:      How many bytes have been sent for this op type
5. bytes_recv:      How many bytes have been received for this op type
6. queue:           How long ops of this type have waited in queue before being
   transmitted (millisecond)
7. rtt:             How long the client waited to receive replies of this op
   type from the server (millisecond)
8. execute:         How long ops of this type take to execute (from
   rpc_init_task to rpc_exit_task) (millisecond)

rpc_run_task ---> rpc_new_task ---> rpc_init_task

The last three time statistics are collected using ns, but they are converted
to ms when they are printed out.

The execute time should approximate to (queue + rtt).

Note, in the Linux source code, the names of the fields are prefixed with
"om_", for example, the first field is "om_ops" instead of "ops".

## NFSv4.0 EXAMPLE

```
device 130.245.177.235:/nfsdata/ mounted on /mnt with fstype nfs4 statvers=1.1
    opts:    rw,vers=4,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,acregmin=3,acregmax=60,
            acdirmin=30,acdirmax=60,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,
            clientaddr=130.245.177.234,minorversion=0,local_lock=none
    age:    19  (time, in seconds, since the NFS is mounted)
    caps:    caps=0xfff7,wtmult=512,dtsize=32768,bsize=0,namlen=255
    nfsv4:    bm0=0xfdffafff,bm1=0xf9be3e,acl=0x0
    sec:    flavor=1,pseudoflavor=1
    events:    0 168232 0 0 0 10095 217808 0 2 9797 0 9739 0 0 19739 19739 0 19739 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    bytes:    1612840960 0 0 0 627536112 0 158076 0
    RPC iostats version: 1.0  p/v: 100003/4 (nfs)
    xprt:    tcp 737 0 1 0 0 69698 69697 0 81817 0 2 1082 12119
    per-op statistics
            NULL: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
            READ: 9797 9797 0 1567520 628138612 71 7953 8200
           WRITE: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          COMMIT: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
            OPEN: 19740 19740 0 4737600 7343280 505 3449 4172
    OPEN_CONFIRM: 10211 10211 0 1552072 694348 74 836 1008
     OPEN_NOATTR: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    OPEN_DOWNGRADE: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
           CLOSE: 19739 19739 0 3316152 2605548 334 3045 3620
         SETATTR: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          FSINFO: 1 1 0 132 108 0 0 0
           RENEW: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     SETCLIENTID: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    SETCLIENTID_CONFIRM: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
            LOCK: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
           LOCKT: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
           LOCKU: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          ACCESS: 96 96 0 14584 19584 0 8 10
         GETATTR: 1 1 0 132 188 0 0 0
          LOOKUP: 10095 10095 0 1655576 2382420 36 898 1072
     LOOKUP_ROOT: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          REMOVE: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          RENAME: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
            LINK: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         SYMLINK: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          CREATE: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        PATHCONF: 1 1 0 128 72 0 0 0
          STATFS: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        READLINK: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         READDIR: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     SERVER_CAPS: 2 2 0 256 176 0 0 0
     DELEGRETURN: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          GETACL: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          SETACL: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    FS_LOCATIONS: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    RELEASE_LOCKOWNER: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         SECINFO: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     EXCHANGE_ID: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    CREATE_SESSION: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    DESTROY_SESSION: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        SEQUENCE: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    GET_LEASE_TIME: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    RECLAIM_COMPLETE: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
       LAYOUTGET: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    GETDEVICEINFO: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    LAYOUTCOMMIT: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    LAYOUTRETURN: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0


NFSv4.1 EXAMPLE
===============
device 130.245.177.235:/nfsdata mounted on /mnt with fstype nfs4 statvers=1.1
    opts:   rw,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,acregmin=3,acregmax=60,acdirmin=30,acdirmax=60,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=130.245.177.234,local_lock=none
    age:    44
    impl_id:    name='',domain='',date='0,0'
    caps:   caps=0x3ffff,wtmult=512,dtsize=32768,bsize=0,namlen=255
    nfsv4:  bm0=0xfdffbfff,bm1=0xf9be3e,bm2=0x800,acl=0x3,sessions,pnfs=not configured
    sec:    flavor=1,pseudoflavor=1
    events: 67379 1692812 0 30749 0 980 1984612 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 96611 96611 0 96611 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    bytes:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    RPC iostats version: 1.0  p/v: 100003/4 (nfs)
    xprt:   tcp 674 0 1 0 0 279772 279771 0 649944 0 5 1711 90409
    per-op statistics
            NULL: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
            READ: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
           WRITE: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          COMMIT: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
            OPEN: 96612 96612 0 27824256 34007424 13349 16253 32061
    OPEN_CONFIRM: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     OPEN_NOATTR: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    OPEN_DOWNGRADE: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
           CLOSE: 96610 96610 0 19708440 17003360 2936 11082 15386
         SETATTR: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          FSINFO: 1 1 0 168 152 0 0 0
           RENEW: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     SETCLIENTID: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    SETCLIENTID_CONFIRM: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
            LOCK: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
           LOCKT: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
           LOCKU: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          ACCESS: 16932 16932 0 3183200 2844576 83 1919 2308
         GETATTR: 67380 67380 0 12128380 15632160 336 8367 10644
          LOOKUP: 1236 1236 0 247176 167784 7 153 197
     LOOKUP_ROOT: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          REMOVE: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          RENAME: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
            LINK: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         SYMLINK: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          CREATE: 980 980 0 219516 305760 5 168 197
        PATHCONF: 1 1 0 164 116 0 0 0
          STATFS: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        READLINK: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         READDIR: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     SERVER_CAPS: 2 2 0 328 280 0 0 0
     DELEGRETURN: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          GETACL: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
          SETACL: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    FS_LOCATIONS: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    RELEASE_LOCKOWNER: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         SECINFO: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     EXCHANGE_ID: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    CREATE_SESSION: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    DESTROY_SESSION: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        SEQUENCE: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    GET_LEASE_TIME: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    RECLAIM_COMPLETE: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
       LAYOUTGET: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    GETDEVICEINFO: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    LAYOUTCOMMIT: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    LAYOUTRETURN: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    SECINFO_NO_NAME: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    TEST_STATEID: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    FREE_STATEID: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    GETDEVICELIST: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    BIND_CONN_TO_SESSION: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    DESTROY_CLIENTID: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0


# vim: tabstop=2:shiftwidth=2:expandtab:foldmethod=indent
```

Also https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/nfs_iostat.h and [https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/NFSMountstatsIndex](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/linux/NFSMountstatsIndex) for additional reading.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no better "documentation" than the [code of the mountstats utility](http://git.linux-nfs.org/?p=steved/nfs-utils.git;a=blob;f=tools/mountstats/mountstats.py).

Answer (score 0):

On what Linux are you doing this because for me, on Redhat, mountstats (for v4) are something like this:

```
[root@riau petri]# cat /proc/1511/mountstats 
device rootfs mounted on / with fstype rootfs
device /proc mounted on /proc with fstype proc
device /sys mounted on /sys with fstype sysfs
device udev mounted on /dev with fstype devtmpfs
device devpts mounted on /dev/pts with fstype devpts
device tmpfs mounted on /dev/shm with fstype tmpfs
device /dev/mapper/vg_riau-lv_root mounted on / with fstype ext4
device /proc/bus/usb mounted on /proc/bus/usb with fstype usbfs
device /dev/sda1 mounted on /boot with fstype ext4
device /dev/mapper/vg_riau-lv_home mounted on /home with fstype ext4
device none mounted on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc with fstype binfmt_misc
device cgroup mounted on /cgroup/cpuset with fstype cgroup
device cgroup mounted on /cgroup/cpu with fstype cgroup
device cgroup mounted on /cgroup/cpuacct with fstype cgroup
device cgroup mounted on /cgroup/memory with fstype cgroup
device cgroup mounted on /cgroup/devices with fstype cgroup
device cgroup mounted on /cgroup/freezer with fstype cgroup
device cgroup mounted on /cgroup/net_cls with fstype cgroup
device cgroup mounted on /cgroup/blkio with fstype cgroup
device sunrpc mounted on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs with fstype rpc_pipefs
device /etc/auto.misc mounted on /misc with fstype autofs
device -hosts mounted on /net with fstype autofs
device nfsd mounted on /proc/fs/nfsd with fstype nfsd
```

Comment: I'm doing this on Ubuntu and it looks like this for nfs mount points

device IPADRESS:/store mounted on /mnt/store with fstype nfs4 statvers=1.0
        opts:   rw,vers=4,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,acregmin=3,acregmax=60,acdirmin=30,acdirmax=60,hard,nointr,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys
        age:    75405
  ...

Comment: @tiflor ah, thats useful, you may consider adding it to your question as an example - that would be most helpful.